# Find given numbers of elements from an unsorted array whose sum equals a given number

Tags: algorithm

Find given numbers of elements from an unsorted array whose sum equals a given number.

I have write the below code, it's almost work. but the complexity is O(n^2). Is there a better solution?

```
(function test(sum = 14, n = 4, nums = [7, 6, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4]) {

  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    var rest = sum
    var ret = []
    var j = i;
    do {
      if (rest - nums[j] >= 0) {
      rest = rest - nums[j]
    } else {
      j++
      continue
    }

    ret.push(nums[j])

    if (rest == 0 && ret.length == n) {
      console.log("done", ret)
    }
    j++
 } while (j < nums.length)

}
})()
```

Comment: Do you have a question, or do you just want someone to do your homework?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I found  some solution those just resolve find a pair of numbers equals given sum.

Comment: You should at least include your code and actual question.  As it stands now, your question looks like a homework dump showing zero effort.

Comment: @JJJ not homework.I just interest in this question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated problem. I'm not do homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a pair of elements from an array whose sum equals a given number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number)

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks . I need to specific number of elements  . that just find a pair of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a hashtable to maintain a list of numbers you visited or list of all numbers in the given array. So at each iteration, you find the complement (given sum - nums[i]). Since you looking for more than a pair of values, you would need to find keys in the hashtable that add up to such complement. The takeaway here is that hashmap has lookup time of O(1)--assuming no/few collisions--whereas iterating through rest of remaining array would result in O(n^2)